# Mongodb unix socket connection with an official mongo-go-driver?

Tags: mongodb, sockets, unix, go

Can't find any information about unix domain sockets connection support with official mongo-go-driver.

Is it implemented and supported officially?

The "mongodb:///tmp/mongodb-27017.sock" uri does not work.

Comment: You might want to try setting the `ClientOptions.Dialer` in the client, and return a connection to the domain socket from the custom dialer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it implemented and supported officially?

Using the official [MongoDB Go driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) you can connect directly to a URI socket. You just need to escape the slash(es). For example using v1.1+:

```
mongoURI := "mongodb://%2Ftmp%2Fmongodb-27017.sock"

client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)
defer cancel()
err = client.Connect(ctx)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

In addition, [mongo.Client](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Client) supports two types of connection string, either:

- [Standard Connection String](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-standard-connection-string-format) format, i.e. `mongodb://user:pwd@mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017,mongodb2.example.com:27017/admin?replicaSet=myRepl`
- [DNS Seedlist Connection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-dns-seedlist) format, i.e `mongodb+srv://server.example.com/`

Please note that MongoDB, by design, is a distributed database (see [Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)). Socket is a file based communication and intended for access within a single machine. Unless your use case and requirements specifically require to connect directly via Unix sockets, I'd recommend to use one of the connection string formats above instead.